# Random invocations for inserting,retrieving and updating mysql to remote and local databases

Tags: java, mysql, linux, jdbc

i have a java program for inserting retrieving and updating to bot remote and local databases at the same time using jdbc.

Currently its working fine.

I have to prepare a testcases to check how it behaves for different situations when so many instance of the same program access a single common remote database with random operations like inserting a record,retrieving a record,multiple instances trying to update a same record..etc

requirement: so,i want to make my program to create that type of environment,where it randomly insert to
remote then retrieve from local,then again retrieve from remote then insert to local....etc like this random invocations i want in my program.

now.its working in a fixed loop like only inserting till loop expires like that i want to make it randomly

how can i implement this.

this is my current code:

```
public class DatabaseOperations {

    Connection localCon = null;
    Connection remoteCon = null;
    List<Connection> connectionsList;
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String user = "root";
    String password = "root";
    String dbName = "my-db";
    String connectionUrl1= "jdbc:mysql://198.1.2.55:3306/"+dbName+"?user="+user+"&password="+password+"&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false&maxReconnects=10";
    String connectionUrl2= "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"+dbName+"?user="+user+"&password="+password+"&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false&maxReconnects=10";

    public List<Connection> createConnection() {

        try {
                    Class.forName(driver);
                    localCon = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl2);
                    if(localCon != null)
                        System.out.println("connected to remote database at : "+new Date());
                    remoteCon = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl1);
                    if(remoteCon != null)
                        System.out.println("connected to local database at : "+new Date());
                    connectionsList = new ArrayList<Connection>( 2 );
                    connectionsList.add( 0 , localCon );
                    connectionsList.add( 1 , remoteCon );
                } catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
                    cnfe.printStackTrace();
                    } catch(SQLException sqle) {
                        sqle.printStackTrace();
                        }
        return connectionsList;
    }

    public void insert() {

        PreparedStatement ps1 = null;
        PreparedStatement ps2 = null;
        String sql = "insert into user1(name, address, created_date)" +
                                " values('xyz', 'saudi', '2013-08-04')";
        List l = this.createConnection();
        Connection localConnection = (Connection)l.get(0);
        Connection remoteConnection = (Connection)l.get(1);
        if(remoteConnection != null&&localConnection != null) {
            System.out.println("Database Connection Is Established");
            try {
                        ps1 = remoteConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
                        ps2 = localConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
                        for(int j=0;j<=7;j++)
                        {
                        int i = ps1.executeUpdate();
                        int k = ps2.executeUpdate();
                        if(i > 0) {
                            System.out.println("Data Inserted into remote database table Successfully");
                            }
                            if(k > 0) {
                            System.out.println("Data Inserted into local database table Successfully");
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        finally {
                            if(remoteConnection != null&&localConnection != null)
                            {
                                try {
                                            remoteConnection.close();
                                            localConnection.close();
                                        } catch (SQLException e) {
                                             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                            }
                            if(ps1 != null&&ps2 != null)
                            {
                                try {
                                            ps1.close();
                                            ps2.close();
                                        } catch (SQLException e) {
                                             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                            }
                        }
        }
    }

    public void retrieve() {

    try {
                List l = this.createConnection();
                Connection localConnection = (Connection)l.get(0);
                Connection remoteConnection = (Connection)l.get(1);
                Statement st1 = localConnection.createStatement();
                Statement st2 = remoteConnection.createStatement();
                ResultSet res1 = st1.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM  user1");
                ResultSet res2 = st2.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM  user1");
                System.out.println("---------------------------Local Database------------------------");
                while (res1.next()) {
                    Long i = res1.getLong("userId");
                    String s1 = res1.getString("name");
                    String s2 = res1.getString("address");
                    java.sql.Date d = res1.getDate("created_date");
                    System.out.println(i + "\t\t" + s1 + "\t\t" + s2 + "\t\t"+ d);
                }
                System.out.println("------------------------Remote Database---------------------");
                while (res2.next()) {
                    Long i = res2.getLong("userId");
                    String s1 = res2.getString("name");
                    String s2 = res2.getString("address");
                    java.sql.Date d = res2.getDate("created_date");
                    System.out.println(i + "\t\t" + s1 + "\t\t" + s2 + "\t\t"+ d);
                }
                localConnection.close();
                remoteConnection.close();
            } catch (SQLException s) {
                System.out.println("SQL code does not execute.");
                s.printStackTrace();
            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    public void update(String userName , String userAddress , int userId) {

        try {
                    List l = this.createConnection();
                    Connection localConnection = (Connection)l.get(0);
                    Connection remoteConnection = (Connection)l.get(1);
                    String sql = "UPDATE user1 SET name = ? , address = ? WHERE userId = ?";
                    PreparedStatement ps1 = localConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
                    PreparedStatement ps2 = remoteConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
                    ps1.setString(1, userName);
                    ps1.setString(2, userAddress);
                    ps1.setInt(3, userId);
                    int i = ps1.executeUpdate();
                    if(i > 0) {
                        System.out.println("Updating Local DB Successfully!");
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Updating Local DB Failed!");
                    }

                    ps2.setString(1, userName);
                    ps2.setString(2, userAddress);
                    ps2.setInt(3, userId);
                    int j = ps2.executeUpdate();
                    if(j > 0) {
                        System.out.println("Updating Remote DB Successfully!");
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Updating Remote DB Failed!");
                    }
                    localConnection.close();
                    remoteConnection.close();
                } catch (SQLException s) {
                    System.out.println("SQL statement is not executed!");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        DatabaseOperations database = new DatabaseOperations();
        database.insert();
        database.retrieve();
        database.update("abc" , "los vegas" , 33767);
    }
}
```

please help me in this,Thanks in advance:

Comment: You can use threads in your case

Comment: @Noman ali abbasi can you please provide me with some example code.

Comment: Please have a look into http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do by using the following code and off course there are many work around too ;)

```
public class MultiThread{

    public void insert(){
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                /*Put your code in run method*/
                System.out.println("Inserting values in db");
            }
        };
        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.start();
    }

    public void update(){
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                /*Put your code in run method*/
                System.out.println("Updating values in db");
            }
        };

        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MultiThread multiThread = new MultiThread();
        multiThread.insert();
        multiThread.update();
    }
}
```

Comment: thankyou i tried this code,its calling inserting once and updating once,if i want call continuosly again and again in randon fashion,what can i do??

Comment: have you tried to put in loop? i didn't get you what you want to achieve?

Comment: i want to achieve random invocations to insert retrieve update methods reccursively..

Comment: I used the above code only first method is happening,but for second method its showing connection closed,why is it happening,where i am opening connections in both the methods separatly??

Comment: you are closing your connections in finally block. try to create a new connection in each method, in your code you are creating connection only once and using them in your all methods as your method complete it will close your connections.

Comment: i am opening in all methods,in all methods i am calling that createConnection method..